# Why is it that SpecFlow 3.1.97's [BeforeTestRun] hook does not execute?

Tags: c#, automated-tests, initialization, hook, specflow

On a project I am working on, we're doing some SpecFlow-based testing.

In past projects, we used the SpecFlow hooks system to set up mocks, limited test data, and other bits of testing infrastructure.  Right now, myself and my team are working on setting up our tests, but we're finding that our test setup isn't happening, because `[BeforeTestRun]` isn't executing.

We discovered this first by not seeing our local database schemas be generated, which we usually do in a `[BeforeTestRun]` method.  Upon setting a breakpoint in the relevant method, and debugging our 'pathfinder' test, we discovered that the `[BeforeScenario]` method is firing, but `[BeforeTestRun]` is not.

The setup we're using is below:

```
[Binding]
public class TestSuite
{
    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void BeforeTestRun()
    {
        // Setup stuff, do whatever.  Set a breakpoint on the next line.
        int x = 1 + 1;     // The breakpoint on this line will not be hit.
    }

    [AfterTestRun]
    public static void AfterTestRun()
    {
        int x = 1 + 1;     // Oddly enough, this one *DOES* get hit.
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public static void BeforeScenario()
    {
        int x = 1 + 1;     // A breakpoint on this line reveals that BeforeScenario gets hit first!
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public static void AfterScenario()
    {
        int x = 1 + 1;     // Because our testing setup gets errors due to not being set up, I can't
                           // honestly say if this gets hit properly.
    }
}
```

...However, `BeforeTestRun` does not get hit, despite checking the following common issues:

- `BeforeTestRun` decorates a static method
- `TestSuite` is decorated with the `[Binding]` attribute

All I can conclude is that either I'm missing something else, or there's an environment issue.  Because I don't know what else I could be missing, here's the environment:

The project is a *.NET Core 3.1 MSTest project*.
The project has the following NuGet packages installed:

- Microsoft.Net.Test.Sdk v16.6.1
- NUnit v3.12.0
- NUnitTestAdapter v3.16.1
- SpecFlow 3.1.97
- SpecFlow.NUnit 3.1.97

**Question:** In what way, given my technology stack, can I get SpecFlow tests to execute the code that is within a static method decorated with `[BeforeTestRun]`?

Comment: Try writing to the standard output instead of debugging: `Console.WriteLine("before test run");` - do you see that in the test output?